# How can I get easy critical hits with the Charge Rifle?

Tags: titanfall

For the Gen 5 challenge "Critically Conditioned: Charge Rifle", I need to get 30 critical hits with the Charge Rifle.  As any good Titan isn't standing in one place very long (and even if they are they are rotating and slightly gyrating), lining up hits is tedious at best.

I had the thought to rodeo and use the Charge Rifle, but while it seems to give a 'red' hit indication around my reticle, my challenge progress is not ticking up any.  I've heard rodeoing is a way to do the challenge, but I'm not sure what I could be doing wrong.  Does the Titan's shields need to be down before a rodeo shot counts as a crit?  Is it bugged? Was it patched?

Answer (score 3):

You are correct in that the Titan's shields need to be down. Additionally, each Titan has a different Critical Hit zone, even in their weak points.

For the Atlas, just fire as normal. Any hit while its shields are down will count as a critical hit. For the Ogre, you allegedly want to shoot at the small vent in the weak area:

[image]

As for Stryders, [you supposedly want to aim at the bottom-center of the weak point](http://www.reddit.com/r/titanfall/comments/22zywp/what_exactly_counts_as_a_crit_with_the_charge/), again, as with the other two, when its shields are down.

That said, I can't guarantee the Ogre or Stryder methods work, as I got all of mine off of Atlas Titans. One useful tip is to play the campaign, specifically the mission "The Three Towers," as the enemy team spawns with two auto-titans being piloted by NPCs. They aren't the brightest, so you should be able to get a few good hits on them.

One last thing, I would highly recommend using any Amped Charge Rifle burn cards. The weapon charges much faster, allowing you to land more hits from a rodeo before their shields recharge. When the shields *do* recharge, you can shoot the arm to take the shield back down, without having to end the rodeo*.

<sup>*unless the arm shot is enough to doom it, though crits still count when it's doomed!</sup>

Comment: One tip when rodeoing the Ogre or the Stryder is to aim away from the exposed "brains" of the titan and shoot at it's back where you would normally see the highlighted red critical areas. They still count for the challenge and are much easier to hit!